# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tcp' of undefined in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, sockets, tcp, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop an extension in chrome which can snoop browser history and send it to a remote machine. I need to establish socket connection for transporting data.
But I am getting the above error. Read a lot of posts online which say there must be errors in the manifest file in context with socket permissions. Can anyone find out the error? Please check the code beneath.

**Manifest File:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Browser History Snooping",
    "description": "This extension snoops browser history and sends it to a remote machine",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "history"
    ],
    "sockets": {
        "tcp": {
            "connect": ""
        }
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var histories = [];
var visits = [];

chrome.history.search({
    text: '',
    maxResults: 0
}, function (historyItems) {
    var historiesProcessed = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < historyItems.length; i++) {
        //histories.push(historyItems[i]);
        console.log(historyItems[i]);

        chrome.history.getVisits({
            url: historyItems[i].url
        }, function (visitItems) {
            for (var i = 0; i < visitItems.length; i++) {
                visits.push(visitItems[i]);
            }
            historiesProcessed++;
            if (historiesProcessed === historyItems.length) {
                console.log(visits.length + ' visits');
            }
        });
    }

    console.log(histories);
});

chrome.sockets.tcp.create({}, function (createInfo) {
    chrome.sockets.tcp.connect(createInfo.socketId, '127.0.0.1', 8888,
        function (result) {
            if (result >= 0) {
                console.log('Successfully connected');
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/28393105/632951

Answer (score 4):

The error is self-explanatory: `chrome.sockets` is undefined.

There's no `sockets` API in the [**extension** documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index), but it is defined for the [chrome apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/sockets).